# Make unison delay synchronization until file transfer is complete

Tags: linux, samba, unison

I have two physical sites with a very slow link between them. Each site has a Linux (Debian 10) server and all clients on those sites are Windows. I'm using Samba for file sharing within the sites, and then using Unison to synchronize both servers.

Everything seems to work fine (with unison `repeat=n`), but when unison kicks in and starts file synchronization whatever file transfers that Samba was performing (uploading a file to the server) are stopped until eventually I get a network error on the Windows machine performing the transfer.

I tried using `repeat=watch` and got it working.  <strike>Now however all file transfers go very slow, since unison is blocking them until it transfers chucks to the other site. They also eventually fail with a network error.</strike>

I thought about making unison-fsmonitor wait until the file transfers are complete before starting the synchronization, but there doesn't seem to be an option like that.

*Unison doesn't block file transfers when watching, turns out I had a problem with the QoS settings that was limiting all traffic through the server.*

Is there some other solution or an alternative software altogether to solve this? Am I missing something?

Comment: A solution could be to write a shell script that emulates the functionality of `repeat=n` or `repeat=watch` by calling Unison manually, but that also checks to make sure Samba isn't doing anything before Unison gets called.